# python2.7 TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, python-2.x

```
#endcding=utf-8
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect{
    host='localhost'
    port=3306,   
    user='root', 
    passwd='admin
    db='db01',   
    charset='utf8
    )            
cur = conn.cursor()
count = cur.execute("select * from t_r_def_audit")
results = cur.fetchmany(count)
provcode = cur.execute("select * from t_r_params where 
param_tag='PROVINCE_CODE' and param_code not in(1,95,99)")
provResults = cur.fetchmany(provcode)
i = 0
sql = "insert into ti_r_audit values({0},{1},{2},{3})"
values = "["
for result in results:
i = i+1
prev = result[8]
audit_id = result[0]
if(prev == "1"):
    prov = 31
    for index in range(prov):
        values =values + "("+str(i)+","+audit_id+",'"+provResults[index]
     [0]+"',0),"
        i = i+1
elif prev=="0":
    values =values + "("+str(i)+","+audit_id+",'"+provResults[31][0]+"',0),"
values = values + "]"
cur.executemany(sql,values)
cur.close
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Manually stitched the parameters of sql, with executableemany implementation of sql, but after the implementation of the script will be reported
The error is as follows

```
λ python audit.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "audit.py", line 34, in <module>
cur.executemany(sql,values)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 255, in 
 executemany
self.errorhandler(self, TypeError, msg)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in 
 defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Write a manual parameters of their own and found no mistakes, indicating that the script should be no problem, the problem may be in the splicing sql parameters, but did not find where there is a problem

Comment: The code you have posted is clearly broken; look at the syntax highlight. Please cut it down to a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a mess, but the line

```
sql = "insert into ti_r_audit values({0},{1},{2},{3})"
```

needs to eventually be called as something along the lines of

```
sql.format('first', 'second', 'third', 'forth')
```

so ensure your list `values` contains 4 values when you call:

```
cur.executemany(sql,values)
```

otherwise you will see the error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Update:

For debugging, you can insert the line:

```
print(sql.format(*values))
```

before you run the line

```
cur.executemany(sql,values)
```

Comment: Sorry, the code is incomplete. My parameters are part of the splicing, values ​​is part of the parameters, I print out, it is indeed four parameters per line

Comment: Check my update and make sure that all of your SQL statements are intact

Comment: Or being given，Print out the amount   “insert into ti_r_audit values([,(,1,,)”